# Python - HardDrive access when opening files

Tags: python, hard-drive

If you open a file for reading, read from it, close it, and then repeat the process (in a loop) does python continually access the hard-drive? Because it doesn't seem to from my experimentation, and I'd like to understand why.

An (extremely) simple example:

```
while True:
    file = open('/var/log/messages', 'r')
    stuff = file.read()
    file.close()
    time.sleep(2)
```

If I run this, my hard-drive access LED lights up once and then the hard-drive remains dormant. How is this possible? Is python somehow keeping the contents of the file stored in RAM? Because logic would tell me that it should be accessing the hard-drive every two seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Likely your operating system or file-system is smart enough to serve the file from the OS cache if the file has not changed in between.

Comment: yes, file caching in the OS optimizes this operation. And all modern OS'es have this feature. On linux check "top" to determine the size of buffer cache.  http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html

Comment: Actually if the OS doesn't do that it is really lame

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your operating system and the type of hard drive you have.  Most of the time, when you access something off the drive, the information is cached in main memory in case you need it again soon.  Depending on the replacement strategy used by your OS, the data may stay in main memory for a while or be replaced relatively soon.

In some cases, your hard drive will cache frequently accessed information in its own memory, and then while the drive might be accessed, it will retrieve the information faster and send it to the processor faster than if it had to search the drive platters.

Comment: Ohkay thanks! It seems Linux is taking care of things for me then.

Comment: Follow-up question... if changes are made to the file while this loop is running, the hard-drive will have to be accessed again to detect those changes, correct?

Comment: @python_anon -- well, again that depends.  In many cases there is a lag between the time a file is actually written to the disk and when it is "written" by a file.  Some OSs have a *write-through* policy, which writes the data immediately to the hard drive, but even then it will replace the cached data with the newly written data, and your file read won't actually go back to the drive again.  In the alternate case, *write-back*, the data is first stored in the cache and eventually goes to the drive.  But in this case, too, your program won't have to explicitly access the drive again.

Comment: So what your saying is changes made to a file are immediately written to the 'copy' of the file thats stored in memory (assuming this file IS in memory)? And these changes might 'wait' to be written to the disk depending on the OS? Very good to know!

Comment: @python_anon -- yes, that's generally the way it works.  There are cases where you can save a file, get confirmation that it is saved, and subsequently have a system crash where you actually lose the data.  That would be very rare because the data is written very frequently, but for some systems that's the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not cache, the operating system does. You can find out the size of these caches with `top`. In the third line, it will say something like:

```
Mem:   5923332k total,  5672832k used,   250500k free,    43392k buffers
```

That means about 43MB are being used by the OS to cache data recently written to or read from the hard disk. You can turn this caching off by writing `2` or `3` to [`/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`](http://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches).